# How to optimise code for cartesian product of HUGE lists in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, cartesian-product

I have only been programming for a few months, but I have done the research and attempted this code.

I currently have 2 files. The first contains ±3 million pairs of protein IDs (strings).
The second contains an enumerated list of each protein, with a unique number assigned to it for each feature it contains: i.e. if proteinA contains 3 features, it will appear as proteinA_1, proteinA_2, proteinA_3. Some proteins can have up to 3000 features.

I want a list of pairs of feature interactions.

My code so far:

```
import csv,itertools, gzip
from collections import Counter
#opens and reads/writes files using csv and gzip   

#1. Counts how many features each protein has in the second file.
cnt = Counter()                     
for row in cfile1:                  
    cnt[row[0]]+=1  

#2. Considers pairs of interacting proteins
for row in cfile2:
    p1 = row[0]; p2=row[1]          

    #3.1. if both proteins have no features, just write the pair to the new file    
    if cnt[p1]==0 and cnt[p2]==0:   
        cout.writerow([p1,p2])

    #3.2. if one protein has no feature, but the other has a feature write e.g. (p1_1,p2) (p1_2,p2) (p1_3,p2)... (p1_k,p2)
    elif cnt[p1]!=0 and cnt[p2]==0: 
        x = cnt[p1]                 
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            p1n=p1+"_%d"%(i)
            cout.writerow([p1n,p2])

    elif cnt[p1]==0 and cnt[p2]!=0:
        x = cnt[p2]
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            p2n=p2+"_%d"%(i)
            cout.writerow([p1,p2n])

    #3.3 if both proteins have features, create a list of the enumerated proteins then get the cartesian product of that list, so that you get all possible f-f interactions
    elif (cnt[p1]!=0) and (cnt[p2]!=0): 
        x = cnt[p1];y = cnt[p2]             
        xprots = []; yprots=[]
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            p1n =p1+"_%d"%(i)
            xprots.append(p1n)
        for i in range(1,y+1):
            p2n=p2+"_%d"%(i)
            yprots.append(p2n)
        for i in itertools.product(xprots,yprots):
            cout.writerow([i[0],i[1]])
```

The code seems to be working correctly, but its taken about 18 hours to get through the first 150000 pairs. So far there are nearly 2 billion interactions in the output file.

Is there anyway, other than maybe cutting out some of the features, that might speed this up. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: please use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for optimization and efficiency type of problems

Comment: I don't see that much room for improvement. If you're stuck with python, you could try an alternative interpreter s.a. [pypy](http://pypy.org/) or [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). PyPy requires all modules to be compatible, but with numba a simple `@autojit` above the most expensive function can get you up to a 1000x speed improvement. You could also rewrite parts of it in cython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is inherent in what you are trying to do, which will take an extraordinarily long time even with the fastest, most optimized low-level C program.

> its taken about 18 hours to get through the first 150000 pairs. So far there are nearly 2 billion interactions in the output file.

Let's look at the numbers. You say there are 3 million protein pairs, and each protein can have up to 3000 features. So the total number of lines in the output will be roughly (3 million) * (3000)^2, which is 27 *trillion*. It looks like each line will contain at least 10 characters (bytes), so we are talking about approximately *270 terabytes* of output.

I doubt your disk is even large enough to store such a file. You need to re-think what you are trying to do; even a 1000x improvement in this code will not change the size of the output, and your program can't be faster than the size of what it's producing. If you really need all that output, your problem may be better suited to parallel computing on a supercomputer or cluster, which will require specialized programming depending on the architecture.

Comment: Thank you @Dan , I will speak to the university about getting a spot on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's little space available for python code optimization. I can recommend you to try and write an extension in C, C++ which will upgrade the performance of the computation to a higher magnitude order.

Writing python extensions is a well documented process and really work very fine for intensive computation applications.

The documentation site on this issue is:
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Pablo, I will definitely look into that. :)